# Can my HOA get its own credit card (or something equivalent)?

Tags: credit-card, non-profit

I'm a volunteer member of my condominium's HOA board.  As part of my volunteering, I helped the HOA set up a DSL account that is used to remotely monitor the building's solar panel array.

This is all working well, but now our Internet ISP wants us to switch over to credit-card based billing rather than mailing us a monthly bill.  For the time being I have given the ISP the numbers of my personal credit card, and the HOA will reimburse me periodically via check.  But this solution isn't entirely satisfactory, since it relies on my continuing availability and will cause problems for the HOA if e.g. I get hit by a bus or something.

Ideally the HOA (or perhaps the HOA's management company) would have its own credit card so that they could handle the automated monthly billing directly, but I'm not sure what the best option is here.  Is it possible for a non-profit/volunteer organization to apply for and get a credit card?  Or is it reasonable to ask the management company set up a credit card account on our behalf?  Or is there some other payment system that would be more appropriate to use, that would act like a credit card (at least as far as the ISP is concerned)?

FWIW the amount of money flowing through this card would be fairly minor, probably less than $50/month.

Comment: Does you HOA have a checking account? Could you use a debit card tied to that account?

Comment: What country are you in? Is it a US HOA?

Comment: @Knuckle-Dragger in the US? Most likely not.

Comment: We're probably living in different United States.

Comment: I am in the USA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using a pre-paid debit card? There are [a large variety of them with different fees and such](http://www.forbes.com/sites/halahtouryalai/2013/07/30/monthly-fees-purchase-fees-reloading-fees-the-best-and-worst-prepaid-cards/), but they don't require the information a credit card would, and it should be the same to the ISP.

Answer (score 2):

If the vendor wants to be able to automatically collect the money, it should be possible for them to pull money from a checking account. That checking account can also have a debit card associated with it.

The local scout units in my area have set up checking accounts with a local bank, that account does allow the account to have a debit/ATM card. Because the card has the VISA logo it looks exactly like the a credit card. That card is in the control of the unit treasurer and can avoid the need for a parent to put down their credit card for big transactions: summer camp, fund raising purchases...